# Extrair atributos de um dataframe usando os pontos de um segundo dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, índices, match, factors

Saudações.

Estou tentando extrair as informações de biomas de um dataframe (biomes_df), que possuem colunas de temperatura e precipitação. Quero usar esses valores pra pra extrair qual são os biomas que os pontos de temp/prec de um outro dataframe (sites) estão. Note que, no df biomes, existem extensões da onde os biomas estão, não é um contínuo.

Pensei em usar as funções match e sp::over, mas não tive muito sucesso. Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço, pois não tenho muito referencial pra resolver isso.

```
biomes_df <- data.frame(
  mat = c(
    29.339, 13.971, 15.371, 17.510, 24.131, 27.074, 28.915, 29.201, 29.339,
    13.971, -9.706, -7.572, 4.491, 17.510, 15.371, 13.971, 17.510, 4.491,
    -7.572, -9.706, -6.687, -0.949, 3.098, 7.147, 10.165, 13.918, 18.626,
    18.176, 17.510, 18.626, 13.918, 10.165,  7.147, 3.098, -0.949, 1.039,
    1.998, 2.444, 3.118, 4.446, 7.758, 12.614, 18.720, 18.637, 18.626, -0.949,
    -6.687, -4.395, -4.098, -1.592, 0.914, 4.155, 3.118, 2.444, 1.998, 1.039,
    -0.949, 18.720,  12.614, 7.758, 4.446, 3.118, 4.155, 15.716, 20.136,
    19.392, 18.720, 18.720, 19.392, 20.136, 22.278, 23.756, 24.199, 24.714,
    25.667, 26.105, 27.414, 27.772, 25.709, 21.736, 18.720, 17.510, 18.176,
    18.626, 18.637, 18.720, 21.736, 25.709, 27.772, 28.418, 28.915, 27.074,
    24.131, 17.510, -6.687, -8.896, -9.706, -13.382, -15.366, -15.217, -8.373,
    -4.098, -1.592, -4.098, -4.395, -6.687
  ),
  map = c(
    21.3, 23.0, 174.6, 535.1, 702.9, 847.9, 992.4, 532.1, 21.3, 23.0, 7.3,
    87.2, 314.6, 535.1, 174.6, 23.0, 535.1, 314.6, 87.2, 7.3, 202.6, 391.7,
    529.9, 783.1, 956.9, 1116.5, 1269.3, 794.3, 535.1, 1269.3, 1116.5, 956.9,
    783.1, 529.9, 391.7, 514.8, 673.4, 968.5, 1630.6, 1839.7, 2028.0, 2224.0,
    2355.7, 1837.6, 1269.3, 391.7, 202.6, 922.9, 1074.1, 1405.9, 1744.9,
    2012.3, 1630.6, 968.5, 673.4, 514.8, 391.7, 2355.7, 2224.0, 2028.0,
    1839.7, 1630.6, 2012.3, 2930.1, 3377.7, 2917.0, 2355.7, 2355.7, 2917.0,
    3377.7, 3896.5, 4343.1, 4415.2, 4429.8, 4279.0, 4113.7, 3344.4, 2790.6,
    2574.0, 2414.3, 2355.7, 535.1, 794.3, 1269.3, 1837.6, 2355.7, 2414.3,
    2574.0, 2790.6, 1920.3, 992.4, 847.9, 702.9, 535.1, 202.6, 50.8, 7.3,
    34.8, 98.8, 170.8, 533.0, 1074.1, 1405.9, 1074.1, 922.9, 202.6
  ),
  biome = c(
    rep('Subtropical desert', 9), rep('Temperate grassland/desert', 7),
    rep('Woodland/shrubland', 13), rep('Temperate forest', 16),
    rep('Boreal forest', 12), rep('Temperate rain forest', 10),
    rep('Tropical rain forest', 14), rep('Tropical seasonal forest/savanna', 13),
    rep('Tundra', 12)
  )
)

sites <- data.frame(site = c("a", "b"), temp = c(-1.2, 27),
                    prec = c(144.6, 207))
```

Comment: Olá, tem como você postar o que tentou e as tabelas iniciais? Que pelo jeito você postou só o data frame final e sem os iniciais ou os passo é difícil dar uma resposta específica

Comment: Olá @JorgeMendes. Todas as minhas tentativas não deram resultados com alguma output, então não reproduzi. Mas atualizei com um df reproduzível também

Comment: map e mat em biomes_df no caso seriam precipitação e temperatura?

Comment: Isso mesmo! No caso, eles têm mais de um valor porque eles formam um polígono que esse bioma pode ocorrer (tentei transformar em SpatialPolygonsDataFrame pra dar usar a função over mas não tive sucesso)

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito acho que é isso que você quer. Usando o `sp` pra criar um polígono e vendo em qual polígono o ponto cai.

Usei a vignette "Map overlay and spatial aggregation in sp" para reproduzir. Não está otimizado porque não conheço muito o pacote mas já parece funcionar.

```r
library(sp)

biomes_df <- data.frame(
  mat = c(
    29.339, 13.971, 15.371, 17.510, 24.131, 27.074, 28.915, 29.201, 29.339,
    13.971, -9.706, -7.572, 4.491, 17.510, 15.371, 13.971, 17.510, 4.491,
    -7.572, -9.706, -6.687, -0.949, 3.098, 7.147, 10.165, 13.918, 18.626,
    18.176, 17.510, 18.626, 13.918, 10.165,  7.147, 3.098, -0.949, 1.039,
    1.998, 2.444, 3.118, 4.446, 7.758, 12.614, 18.720, 18.637, 18.626, -0.949,
    -6.687, -4.395, -4.098, -1.592, 0.914, 4.155, 3.118, 2.444, 1.998, 1.039,
    -0.949, 18.720,  12.614, 7.758, 4.446, 3.118, 4.155, 15.716, 20.136,
    19.392, 18.720, 18.720, 19.392, 20.136, 22.278, 23.756, 24.199, 24.714,
    25.667, 26.105, 27.414, 27.772, 25.709, 21.736, 18.720, 17.510, 18.176,
    18.626, 18.637, 18.720, 21.736, 25.709, 27.772, 28.418, 28.915, 27.074,
    24.131, 17.510, -6.687, -8.896, -9.706, -13.382, -15.366, -15.217, -8.373,
    -4.098, -1.592, -4.098, -4.395, -6.687
  ),
  map = c(
    21.3, 23.0, 174.6, 535.1, 702.9, 847.9, 992.4, 532.1, 21.3, 23.0, 7.3,
    87.2, 314.6, 535.1, 174.6, 23.0, 535.1, 314.6, 87.2, 7.3, 202.6, 391.7,
    529.9, 783.1, 956.9, 1116.5, 1269.3, 794.3, 535.1, 1269.3, 1116.5, 956.9,
    783.1, 529.9, 391.7, 514.8, 673.4, 968.5, 1630.6, 1839.7, 2028.0, 2224.0,
    2355.7, 1837.6, 1269.3, 391.7, 202.6, 922.9, 1074.1, 1405.9, 1744.9,
    2012.3, 1630.6, 968.5, 673.4, 514.8, 391.7, 2355.7, 2224.0, 2028.0,
    1839.7, 1630.6, 2012.3, 2930.1, 3377.7, 2917.0, 2355.7, 2355.7, 2917.0,
    3377.7, 3896.5, 4343.1, 4415.2, 4429.8, 4279.0, 4113.7, 3344.4, 2790.6,
    2574.0, 2414.3, 2355.7, 535.1, 794.3, 1269.3, 1837.6, 2355.7, 2414.3,
    2574.0, 2790.6, 1920.3, 992.4, 847.9, 702.9, 535.1, 202.6, 50.8, 7.3,
    34.8, 98.8, 170.8, 533.0, 1074.1, 1405.9, 1074.1, 922.9, 202.6
  ),
  biome = c(
    rep('Subtropical desert', 9), rep('Temperate grassland/desert', 7),
    rep('Woodland/shrubland', 13), rep('Temperate forest', 16),
    rep('Boreal forest', 12), rep('Temperate rain forest', 10),
    rep('Tropical rain forest', 14), rep('Tropical seasonal forest/savanna', 13),
    rep('Tundra', 12)
  )
)

sites <- data.frame(site = c("a", "b"), temp = c(-1.2, 27),
                    prec = c(144.6, 207))

biomes_list <- split(biomes_df[,1:2], biomes_df$biome)

biomes_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(biomes_list[[1]])), ID=names(biomes_list[1])), 
  Polygons(list(Polygon(biomes_list[[2]])), ID=names(biomes_list[2])), 
  Polygons(list(Polygon(biomes_list[[3]])), ID=names(biomes_list[3])), 
  Polygons(list(Polygon(biomes_list[[4]])), ID=names(biomes_list[4])),
  Polygons(list(Polygon(biomes_list[[5]])), ID=names(biomes_list[5]))
  ))

sites_points <- sites[,2:3]
dimnames(sites_points)[[1]] <- sites[,1]
sites_points <- SpatialPoints(sites_points)

sites_categories <- over(sites_points, biomes_poly, returnList = TRUE)

sites["categories"] <- names(biomes_list)[as.numeric(sites_categories)]

sites
#>   site temp  prec                 categories
#> 1    a -1.2 144.6 Temperate grassland/desert
#> 2    b 27.0 207.0         Subtropical desert
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Era exatamente o que precisava. Eu cheguei a ver esse vignette, mas não tenho domínio o suficiente pra conseguir adaptar pro meu. Agradeço.

Comment: Bom que ajudou ! Se puder aceite a resposta aqui também :)